# Power Shell version 1 http

Tags: powershell

So i am a beginner at powershell and would appreciate some help, what i need to do is to be able to send a commadns to multiple devices with as little code as possible. so far i can send to a single device at a time with the below code

```
$Body = [byte[]][char[]]'asdf';
$Request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::CreateHttp('http://172.25.183.2/axis-cgi/restart.cgi');
$Request.Method = 'POST';
$Request.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("root", "pass");
$Stream = $Request.GetRequestStream();
$Stream.Write($Body, 0, $Body.Length);
$Request.GetResponse();
```

so for example i would like to send to multiple devices similar as you do with curl

```
curl "http://root:pass@10.21.1.(196,197,198,199,200}/axis-cgi/restart.cgi"
```

The above works as expected but i need to send to more than 200 devices, also i need to be able to use powershell version 1 so it is compatible with all windows versions from windows 7 onward.

Any help appreciated

Comment: pleease note that windows 7 is shipped with ps version **2**  (look at `$PSVersionTable`)

Comment: How do you get your devices list ? From a file containing the ip addresses ?

Comment: Thank you kayasax, strange my current version of powershell on windows 7 is powershell version 1, willt ake a look into it. The easiest method for me would be to have the IP addresses in the same powershell script.

Comment: the powershell executable sits on V1.0 directory even with PS version 2,3,4&5 ;)

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, i just need to make sure that the script will work on any windows machine, even if they have PS 1,2,3,4,5 :)

Comment: I'm downvoting because of double post : [Powershell invoke web request to multiple targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427476/powershell-invoke-web-request-to-multiple-targets)

Comment: I wouldn't focus on getting a script working for PS version 1 since there is no supported Windows version that doesn't support at least PS2. PS1 also kinda sucks compared to v2 (v2 actually sucks compared to v3, I hardly develop for v2 because I rather upgrade a machine or all machines to v3 or higher because that's far less work then writing scripts for multiple versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this (it will send the request to device from 172.25.183.196 to 172.25.183.200 ):

```
(196..200)| foreach{
   $Body = [byte[]][char[]]'asdf';
   $Request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::CreateHttp("http://172.25.183.$_/axis-cgi/restart.cgi");
   $Request.Method = 'POST';
   $Request.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("root", "pass");
   $Stream = $Request.GetRequestStream();
   $Stream.Write($Body, 0, $Body.Length);
   $Request.GetResponse();

}
```

Comment: i tried that but the problem is the the $_ in the url is unable to be parsed

Comment: replace `'`by `"` to allow variable expansion  ie `$Request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::CreateHttp("http://172.25.183.$_/axis-cgi/restart.cgi")`

Comment: perfect thank you, that worked, not really a coder i try and dabble a little bit now and again but the problem is i always forget :) thank you for all you help :)